# Unable to add to class elements ArrayList inside DrawView

Tags: android, arraylist, addition, indexoutofboundsexception

i am trying to add a class element to an array list in side the draw view. unfortunately the add function is not adding the required element.. 
Here is my DrawView class.

pls look inside the drawgame and on size changed function.

the problem seems to be that the size of array list remains 0 instead of 2. and so the function shows IndexOutOfBoundExeption..

```
public class DrawView extends View {
int i=0;
float flag=0;
float bubrank=2;   
ArrayList<bubble1> bub1 ;
Context mContext;
private int width, hieght;


public DrawView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,attrs);
    mContext = context;       
    bub1 = new ArrayList<bubble1>();       

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawgame(canvas);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(15);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    width = w;
    hieght = h;
    for (i = 0; i < bubrank; i++) {
        bub1.get(i).setbound(0, 0, width, hieght);            
    }


}

public void drawgame(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    for (i = 0; i <bubrank; i++)
        bub1.add(new bubble1(Color.BLUE, mContext));
    bub1.get(0).draw(canvas);
    ...............................
```

........................................................

please help.... thankyou.

Comment: If you already know the arraylist is going to have a size of 2, why not initialize it as `new ArrayList<bubble1>(2);`

Comment: i have tried that but dint work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in drawgame(), it is in onSizeChanged(), in the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < bubrank; i++) {
bub1.get(i).setbound(0, 0, width, hieght);            
}
```

The problem is that onSizeChanged is a "callback" method - it is called by the system without your knowledge before you have called drawgame() - the ArrayList has not been filled yet. You need to do what the professor did in the Shooting game.

```
for (i = 0; i < bub1.size(); i++) {
bub1.get(i).setbound(0, 0, width, hieght);            
}
```

this solved the problem...